# NodeJS, Express, Jade, MySQL, Socket.io Boilerplate?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

Does anyone know of a boilerplate combining Express, Jade, Socket.io, and MySQL? All of the ones I'm able to find use a noSQL DB. I might have to just write my own templates to use, but would hate to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried: https://github.com/robrighter/node-boilerplate but it has most of what your after.

I can suggest using express as the boilerplate:

```
npm install -g express
```

So after you'll globally install it, you could do something like:

```
express newApp
```

which will create a new dir named newApp and populate it with the boilerplate of the framework.
(you can follow http://expressjs.com/guide.html)
afterwards, you can "cd newApp" and run

```
npm install
```

this will read the dependencies from package.json and will download the node.js modules required.
for socket.io , just run

```
npm install socket.io
```

as for jade, it's the default templating engine of express, it's built in.
Regarding mySQL , there are tones of options: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-db-mysql

you just have to choose. If your after ORM, i can recommend: https://github.com/sdepold/sequelize

Hope this helps.